# Anylogic Help- How do i change an imported 3dobject color when it passes through several 'stations' on a conveyor?

Tags: java, colors, anylogic, simulate

I am trying to simulate an imported 3d object passing through several 'stations' with a different color change as it passes through stations but I am unable to do it.
Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: is it a "standard" 3D object (as in your question) or an "imported" one (as in your title)? Please be specific, the answer depends on this ;)

Comment: Also, do the "Lead Acid Battery Production Model" tutorial in the AnyLogic help, it does what you are looking for. Last, Google is your friend: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56123491/how-to-change-material-color-of-any-3d-object-in-anylogic-using-code

Comment: Hi Benjamin, Sorry for the confusion, it is an imported 3d object only.

Comment: I will look into the lead-acid battery production model tutorial and I did see your answer to a similar question on stack overflow but I can't seem to get it to work.I tried to use the "agent.3dobjectname.setFillColor(color)" in the "on process finished" box under each station's properties but I get build errors. Can you help me fix this issue? and thank you for taking the time to help me.Really appreciate it.

Comment: if you did setFillColor, you clearly didn't read any of the things Ben suggested

Comment: If you get build errors, please either re-edit this question or start a new one. And please first of all study how to ask good questions here to make our lives easy :) https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Hi Felipe I apologize if I was not clear, I did try to use ".setColor(materialname,color)" which gave me erros so i tried it the other way.

Comment: Hi Benjamin, Thanks for the help,i used the lead acid battery production model tutorial to solve my issue.Thanks so much.

Comment: Can you suggest any websites/blogs for more anylogic tutorials/tips/tricks?thank you

Comment: Hi @user15357197, if the reply helded, please upvote it to help future users with similar issues :) Also, please open new questions when you have ... new questions :) (see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask )

Comment: Hi benjamin, i would have definitely upvoted it if I could, unfortunately it doesn't me allow me upvote on my own post.